# Is there a way to make long delay ink?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment, color

I would like to make some invisible ink that apears by itself after some time, preferably at least a couple of days. I want to write a dedication in a book with it, so it would probably be fine if the colour apears after half an hour of air exposure. Is this even possible using easy to get ingredients?

Comment: Some organic molecule with colored oxidation product and low oxidation rate, dissolved on solvent, but cant think none in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You might experiment with fresh-ground apples, which contain polyphenol oxidase and catechol oxidase, enzymes that turn brown in air (a tiny amount of copper or ferrous salt is also present, acting as a catalyst).

For that matter, dilute ferrous salts are often almost colorless (pale green) but darken to brown on exposure to air. ([Digging in a podzol, soil of a pine forest, shows that color change.](https://books.google.com/books?id=sozsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=podzol%20darkens%20exposure%20to%20air&source=bl&ots=JyyQ3YSw1I&sig=G4Jl18FNAxSmwyOPhVI0UhJULz0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIzaTFt4nQxwIVgnU-Ch02ig9E#v=onepage&q=podzol%20darkens%20exposure%20to%20air&f=false)) So, you could extract a bit of liquid from greenish podzool and load your pen or marker with that.